# Submediant chords to repeat a song

Tags: chord-progressions

So I wanna extend the song by replacing the last two chords from `5 - 1` to `5 - 6` or `3M/3 - 6` (Does this make sense? Hehe). For example, in the key of C, I would like to repeat the song by replacing `G7-C` to `G7-Am7` or `E7/G#-Am7`. Thing is I don't know what chord next to play before actually repeating the last line or 2 of the song--in the case of the example, a chord after Am7. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This V–vi motion is often called a "deceptive cadence" (or an "interrupted cadence" in British English). In most cases a deceptive cadence leads into what some call the "one-more-time technique" where the composer will "try again" to reach a V–I cadence.

The standard method of "trying again" is to move to a Predominant and restart the cadential process. As such, how about moving to IV or ii after the Am7?

This isn't the only method, but it is a standard one. You can even elaborate a motion to IV by moving from Am7 to a C7/G and then to IV, creating a nice 6–5–4 motion in the bass that smoothly leads to your IV. Alternatively, move from Am7 through A7/G to a Dm/F!

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. How about if the 4th (in this case F) becomes 2M/3 (in this case, D7/F#)?

Comment: @tjvg1991 Completely fine, at which point that chord just becomes an applied dominant to V!

Comment: what can be the chord before that? C7/G? A7/G? @Richard

Comment: @tjvg1991 A7/G would probably sound better.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what chord is at the beginning of the 'last line or 2' of the song.  Pick a progression that leads into it nicely.